# Codility Permutation Assignment

Tags: ruby, algorithm, big-o

I'm doing the permutation task on codility.com. The goal is basically to check if the the array passed as exactly one element matching the permutation in its size. I.E. for an `array size N` it should include the values `1,2,3...N` each exactly once. I managed to get the logic correct how ever my score on the complexity was horrible `0(N**2)`. How can I improve this?

```
def solution(a)
  return 0 unless a.uniq == a
  set = (1..a.size).to_a 
  for n in set
    return 0 unless a.include? n
  end
  1
end
```

Comment: Not the most efficient, but an easy way would be: `(a.sort == (1..a.size).to_a) ? 1 : 0`.

Comment: Another way: `b=(1..a.size).to_a; (b-a).empty? && (a-b).empty? ? 1 : 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be inclined to do it as follows.  I have not dealt with the possibilities of `a` being empty or containing elements other than Fixnums.

```
def solution(a)
  (a.uniq == a && a.min == 1 && a.max == a.size) ? 1 : 0
end

solution([1,2,3,4,5])   #=> 1
solution([1,2,5,3,4])   #=> 1
solution([1,2,3,5,6])   #=> 0
solution([1,2,5,4,2])   #=> 0
solution([1,2,2,4,5])   #=> 0
solution([1,2,5,4,6])   #=> 0
```

Comment: this works great with the exception that i need a 0 or 1 return value `def solution(a)
  val = a.uniq == a && a.min == 1 && a.max == a.size
  return 0 unless val
  1
end`

Answer (score 1):

You can just use another array to keep track of which values 1..N you have seen. I dont know ruby so heres some pseudocode

```
solution(A)
  N = size(A)
  bool[] seen = bool[N]
  for i from 0 to N-1
  {
    number = A[i]
    if (number < 1 || number > N || seen[number])
      return false
  }
  return true;
```